# Error while converting from std::wstring to wchar_t*

Tags: c++, c++11

I converted the following code containing std::wstring to wchar_t (next code block) and I am getting memory dump errors:

Below is code with std::wstring:

```
std::wstring RemoveFirstAndLast(std::wstring str)
{
    std::wstring removeFirst = L"";
    bool first = true;
    for (std::wstring::iterator it = str.begin(); it != str.end(); ++it)
    {
        const wchar_t *brckt = L"[";
        const wchar_t *empty = L" ";
        const wchar_t *curlyBrkt = L"{";
        if (((*it) == (*curlyBrkt)) && (first))
        {
            first = false;
            removeFirst = removeFirst + (*it);
        }
        else
        {
            removeFirst = removeFirst + (*it);
        }
    }

    std::wstring removeLast = L"";
    bool last = true;
    for (std::wstring::reverse_iterator it = removeFirst.rbegin(); it != removeFirst.rend(); ++it)
    {
        const wchar_t *brckt = L"]";
        const wchar_t *empty = L" ";
        const wchar_t *curlyBrkt = L"}";

        if (((*it) == (*curlyBrkt)) && (last))
        {
            last = false;
            removeLast = (*it) + removeLast;
        }
        else
        {
            removeLast = (*it) + removeLast;
        }
    }

    return removeLast;
}
```

Below is the same code as above but with wchar_t*:

```
wchar_t* RemoveFirstAndLast(wchar_t *str)
{
    wchar_t *removeFirst = L"";
    int length = wcslen(str);
    bool first = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        const wchar_t *brckt = L"[";
        const wchar_t *empty = L" ";
        const wchar_t *curlyBrkt = L"{";
        if (((str[i]) == (*curlyBrkt)) && (first))
        {
            first = false;
            wcsncat_s(removeFirst, (wcslen(removeFirst) + 1) * 2, &str[i], 1);  //removeFirst = removeFirst + (str[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            wcsncat_s(removeFirst, (wcslen(removeFirst) + 1) * 2, &str[i], 1);  //removeFirst = removeFirst + (str[i]);
        }
    }

    wchar_t *removeLast = L"";
    length = wcslen(removeFirst);
    bool last = true;
    for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        const wchar_t *brckt = L"]";
        const wchar_t *empty = L" ";
        const wchar_t *curlyBrkt = L"}";
        if (((removeFirst[i]) == (*curlyBrkt)) && (last))
        {
            last = false;
            wchar_t *temp2 = (wchar_t*)calloc((wcslen(removeLast) * 2) + 1, sizeof(wchar_t));
            wcsncat_s(temp2, (wcslen(temp2)) * 2, &removeFirst[i], 1);
            wcsncat_s(temp2, (wcslen(temp2)) * 2, removeLast, wcslen(removeLast));
            removeLast = temp2;
        }
        else
        {
            wchar_t *temp3 = (wchar_t*)calloc((wcslen(removeLast) * 2) + 1, sizeof(wchar_t));
            wcsncat_s(temp3, (wcslen(temp3)) * 2, &removeFirst[i], 1);
            wcsncat_s(temp3, (wcslen(temp3)) * 2, removeLast, wcslen(removeLast));
            removeLast = temp3;
            //removeLast = (removeFirst[i]) + removeLast;
        }
    }

    return removeLast;
}
```

The code is trying to remove first and last characters. As a beginner I was trying to understand why I am getting errors while simply converting the code from std::wstring to wchar_t*? The error creates a memory dump? Can someone please help me understand as to where am I making mistake?

Comment: What specific "memory dump errors"?

Comment: Use your debugger and your compiler's address sanitizer. Both are valuable sources of information and great tools for figuring out any memory problems the code has.

Comment: `wcsncat_s(removeFirst (...` is fundamentally broken since you did not allocate any memory for  `removeFirst `.  In fact, I'm surprised that `wchar_t *removeFirst = L"";` compiles - it should be `const wchar_t *removeFirst = L"";`, if compiling the code as C++.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Thanks bang on...this is helpful. Can you please help me understand how I can allocate memory this will be super useful.

Comment: @chris: These are the type of errors Paul is talking about

Comment: @ScottHunter: It is the same error as Paul is talking about

Comment: Allocate initially, with `malloc` (or `calloc`).  To grow the string later, use `realloc`.

Comment: @jl -- On a high-level, what is this code supposed to do?  I get the feeling that a couple of algorithm function calls or similar would accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish much more safely and simpler.  My "no raw loops" radar is going off.

Comment: Is the code supposed to simply remove all of the opening and closing brackets from the string?  If so, `std::remove_if` would have been a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul states - `std::wstring` does all of the memory allocation and copy/move for you.  When you use `wchar_t*` you are dealing with naked pointers which must address memory that you have allocated in some way.  Note you are already doing this with `calloc` further down.

When dealing with widestrings you need to be careful about whether counts are "number of bytes" or "number of characters" since they are not equivalent.  It's best to name variables to indicate what units they are working with.

The assignment `wchar_t *removeFirst = L"";` may also set the pointer to address a "string literal constant" which may reside in a non-writable area of memory.  In any case you won't be able to concatenate anything to it.  Instead you have to provide a buffer that starts with a zero widechar to provide an "empty string that can be concatenated".  Since you are looking to remove characters from the string, you can allocate a widechar buffer that's the length of the original string, and work with that buffer for accumulating the result.  So you can do

```
 size_t original_string_length_widechars = wcslen(str);
 size_t processing_buffer_length_widechars = original_string_length_widechars + 1;
 wchar_t* processing_buf = (wchar_t*)calloc(processing_buffer_length_widechars, sizeof(wchar_t));
```

Adding 1 provides room for a zero widechar terminator (to accommodate the case where nothing is removed from the string).  It doesn't matter that you may be over-allocating (akin to using `reserve` in a vector); the buffer simply needs to be large enough to accommodate the processing you're doing (in this case, copying widechars from the original string without the first and last brackets).

The concatenation functions (e.g. `wcsncat_s`) do not reserve memory for you; they simply copy characters to a buffer that you should have provided enough room to accomodate the result of the concatenation.

Put another way, you have to think differently about string manipulation.  Instead of thinking "add these two strings together", in C, you need to think of "reserve a buffer to accommodate the result and fill it by concatenating strings within it".

If you're only looking to copy what's between the first and last delimiters then you would simply fill the processing buffer as follows:

```
wchar_t const* position_of_first_char_after_start_delimiter;
wchar_t const* position_of_last_delimiter;

// scan the original str to determine values for these ^^^

// note that pointer arithmetic in C takes the size of the pointer types into account; you don't need to divide this by 2......
size_t num_chars_to_copy = position_of_last_delimiter - position_of_first_char_after_start_delimiter;

wcsncpy_s (processing_buf,
           processing_buffer_length_widechars,
           position_of_first_char_after_start_delimiter,
           num_chars_to_copy);
```

---

Also, this section looks dodgy..... the string indices are 0 to (length-1).  Accessing `string[length]` may invoke unintended behaviour.

```
length = wcslen(removeFirst);
...
for (int i = length; i >= 0; i--)
{
...
 if (((removeFirst[i]) == (*curlyBrkt)) && (last))
```

---

Also you shouldn't need to be "doubling up" everything when using the widestring functions - plus in `calloc` you are correctly declaring that each element's size is that of a widechar.

---

The function signature `wchar_t* RemoveFirstAndLast(wchar_t *str)`  simply returns a naked pointer.  There needs to be a comment to state whether memory has been allocated for it and whether the caller needs to release it.  Generally you should avoid imposing such requirements on the caller if you can (unless it's specifically intended).

Given the function is meant to trim an already allocated string, you may want to consider trimming `str` in-place.  If `str` cannot be modified then it needs to be declared a pointer to constant widechars, i.e. `wchar_t const* str` (read right-to-left).

Comment: Assuming `length` is the string length, then `string[length]` would be the zero-termination, and accessing it should be perfectly fine.

Comment: how can I assign a string literal wchar_t *removeFirst = L""; and later append to it

Comment: You cannot "assign a string literal ... and later append to it" like that, C++ does not work this way.